# Cannot Switch TabItem from DoubleClick Event

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am trying to change the selected tab of my TabControl using the following code:

```
// Switch to configuration tab
tabControl.SelectedItem = configTab;
```

While it works just fine from within a ButtonClick handler, it does nothing from within a DataGrid DoubleClick handler on the same TabItem. I have set the debugger to this line and can see the SelectedItem property change, but the tab refuses to change.

**EDIT:** More Code

The tab control is defined as such:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Padding="0" SelectionChanged="BuildSummary">
        <TabItem Header="Configurations" Name="configTab">
            ...
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Temperature" Name="tempTab">
            ...
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test List" Name="testTab">
            ...
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Summary" Name="summaryTab">
            ...
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

This is the working event:

```
private void Execute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Switch to configuration tab
    tabControl.SelectedItem = configTab;
}
```

This is the broken event:

```
private void DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(
        (DataGrid)sender, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) 
        as DataGridRow;

    if (row == null)
        return;

    /* code here prepares the configuration tab */
    ...

    // Switch to configuration tab
    tabControl.SelectedItem = configTab;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Particularly, how `configTab` is obtained and how your `TabControl.ItemsSource` is bound/created?

Comment: configTab is the name of the TabItem, defined in XAML[br]TabControl.ItemsSource is created automatically by the XAML file as well, based on the elements of <TabControl>

Comment: Does it get as far as firing BuildSummary?  Put in a Try Catch block to get the error message.

Comment: BuildSummary is fired. In this method, the tabControl.SelectedItem property does show as the configuration tab. No errors are generated.

Comment: Wow.  I would try setting e.handled = true as it might somehow be firing the base().   You might try setting SelectedIndex.  Those are just reaches.  But if no error is thrown then something else has to making that happen.

Comment: e.handled = true did the trick! It must have been passing the click event up to the tabitem somehow, overriding my command. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
e.handled = true;
```

to stop the click event from propagating up from the DataGrid to the current TabItem

~BalamBalam

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your Double-Click event is being hit at all?

I believe the `DataGrid` marks some of it's click events as handled, so they don't pass through to other events. It's possible you're using one of these events. If so, you'll have to switch to handling the double-click event at another level, such as on the `DataGridCell`.